# How do people conjugate incorporated verbs into Perfektum?

Tags: word-choice

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incorporation_(linguistics)

Incorporated verbs include *radfahren*, *staubsaugen* etc. Different sites show different results:

https://da.wiktionary.org/wiki/staubsaugen

https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/staubsaugen.htm

So there are *staubgesaugt* and *gestaubsaugt*. Which is more frequent used and what about other incorporated verbs?

In the case of *staubsaugen*, it can be transitive or intransitive, i.e. *Ich staubsauge* and *Ich staubsauge den Teppich*. These may be regarded separately.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly about considering the incorporated noun as an inseparable prefix or not.

> Ich sauge gerade Staub. *(plain)*
>
> Ich staubsauge gerade. *(people say this!)*
>
> Ich habe Staub gesaugt.
>
> Ich habe staubgesaugt.
>
> Ich habe gestaubsaugt. *(a bit odd, but see above, inseparable is okay.)*

All okay!

> Ich fahre gerade Rad. *(plain)*
>
> <s>Ich radfahre gerade.</s> *(nobody says this!)*
>
> Ich bin Rad gefahren.
>
> Ich bin radgefahren.
>
> <s>Ich bin geradfahren.</s> *(nobody says this!)*

So, the separable variant is always possible, while the inseparable variant is often not possible.

**EDIT:** I think you are right about your notion of a separate accusative object. It leads to the inseparable form.